# AnyLogic: Some time resource pool moves to destination without having agent

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Problem is explained in the image below

[image]

The detail of the agent which I am using:

[image]

[image]

Detail on the Service in which I am using Resource Pool:

[image]

Process Flow:

[image]

**I used seize-move-release, in order to move the agent with the Resource. showing in figure below**
[image]
**Problem:**
Now the only problem is, how 2 Agents will wait in the queue for there turn to go to the Delay section. Explanation is in the image below.
[image]

Comment: show your process flow

Comment: I added the process flow diagram too. kindly take a look and let me know if you need more information.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it seems that most of this flow is wrong if your intent is for the resource to take the agent somewhere.

You are looking at the resource move alone because it's probably going back home

In order to use the resource to move your agent, you need to use seize-move-release, not a service block

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @Felipe for your help. I used seize-move-release for moving the agents through resources and I work. Now the only problem is, that I want 2 agents to wait in the queue for their turn to get moved by the resources to their destination.
I also added the detail with screenshots at the end.
Thank you.